# gpg-agent ignoring cache config macOS sierra

Tags: bash, encryption, gnupg, gpg-agent

I installed gpg via homebrew.

I have a ~/gpg-agent.conf file as follows:

```
allow-preset-passphrase
default-cache-ttl 1209600
max-cache-ttl 1209600
max-cache-ttl-ssh 1209600
```

My .bashrc (*actually*: `~/.bash_it/custom/gpg-agent.bash`) has

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)

[ -f ~/.gpg-agent-info ] && source ~/.gpg-agent-info
if [ -S "${GPG_AGENT_INFO%%:*}" ]; then
  export GPG_AGENT_INFO
else
  eval $( /usr/local/bin/gpg-agent --daemon --write-env-file ~/.gpg-agent-info )
fi
```

My assumption was this would make it so that I'm only asked for my passphrase once every 2 weeks, but I'm still asked for it every 5 minutes. `gpg-agent --gpgconf-list` shows the actual values being used?

```
$ gpg-agent --gpgconf-list
gpgconf-gpg-agent.conf:16:"/Users/notbrain/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
verbose:8:
quiet:8:
debug-level:24:"none:
log-file:8:
default-cache-ttl:24:600:
default-cache-ttl-ssh:24:1800:
max-cache-ttl:24:7200:
max-cache-ttl-ssh:24:7200:
enforce-passphrase-constraints:8:
min-passphrase-len:24:8:
min-passphrase-nonalpha:24:1:
check-passphrase-pattern:24:
max-passphrase-days:24:0:
enable-passphrase-history:8:
no-grab:8:
ignore-cache-for-signing:8:
no-allow-mark-trusted:8:
no-allow-external-cache:8:
disable-scdaemon:8:
enable-ssh-support:0:
```

Why is my gpg-agent.conf file not being obeyed? What am I missing? Installed via homebrew:

```
$ ll $(which gpg)
8 lrwxr-xr-x  1 notbrain  admin    33B Mar  1 15:15 /usr/local/bin/gpg -> ../Cellar/gnupg2/2.0.30_3/bin/gpg
```

Comment: This should be moved over to apple.stackexchange.com, I think. But I can answer here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You've put the `gpg-agent.conf` file in your home directory at `~/.gpg-agent.conf`. But the default location for that file is in a subdirectory: `~/.gpg/gpg-agent.conf`.

In the [`gpg-agent` configuration documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Configuration.html#Agent-Configuration) they say the `gpg-agent.conf` file should be in the "current home directory". But, confusingly, they don't mean the user's home directory; they mean [gpg-agent's home directory](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html#option-_002d_002dhomedir): `~/.gpg`.

So you can move your config file to `~/.gpg/gpg-agent.conf` and it should be found. Alternatively, you can give `gpg-agent` a new home directory using the `--homedir [dir]` flag on startup.

Comment: I think you misread the output - it's in .gnupg/gpg-agent.conf in my home directory. I should answer this that it took a restart for gpg-agent to pick up the configs I set. A simple relaunch of iterm2 did not cut it.

Comment: weird, my default directory is `.gnupg`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was just an issue with a simple logout/login and/or relaunch of iterm2 not working. It started to work once I rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

using MacOS Monterery, was facing the same issue found after an hour that the passphrase was being cached by macos keychain and to disable this go to **System Preferences > GPG Suite** and **uncheck - Store in macOS Keychain** option. The saved passphrases are still tried once, will be great to delete them as well ( delete button to the right of above option ). Caching time can also be configured in GPG Suite using the `Remember for _ option`.